# Javascript Regular Expressions - Required field validation

Tags: javascript, validation

How do I check if a field (textbox) is empty or filled only with white spaces (spaces/enters/tabs etc.), using javascript RegExp?

Answer (score 15):

```
if (myField.value.match(/\S/)) {
  // field is not empty
}
// or
if (/\S/.test(myField.value)) {
  // field is not empty
}
```

Explanation, since other people seem to have some <strike>crazy</strike> different ideas:

`\s` will match a space, tab or new line.
`\S` will match anything but a space, tab or new line.
If your string has a single character which is not a space, tab or new line, then it's not empty.
Therefore you just need to search for one character: `\S`

Comment: test() is on the RegExp object: "/\S/.test(myField.value)"

Comment: ya, i always get those two mixed up.

Comment: I like the simplicity of the approach. But I don't think negated negative logic ("if not value contains non-space chars") contributes a lot to code comprehensibility.

Answer (score 5):

```
/^\s*$/.test(string)
```

Could be used like so:

```
var empty_string = /^\s*$/; //create RegExp object for re-use

if (empty_string.test(myFormField.value))
{
  alert("Please be a bit more elaborate!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By testing for

```
/\s/ or /\S/
```

you will only be testing for one character . So , it will be better to test instead for :

```
/^\s+$/ or /^\S+$/
```

EDIT: please note that **or** is not part of the code .

EDIT2:

The test for matching :

```
if(string.match(/^\s+$/)) {
   alert("string is empty!");
}
```

And the test for non-matching :

```
if(!string.match(/^\S+$/)) {
   alert("string is empty!");
}
```

You could use either of these to same result .

Comment: The latter will fail for the empty string. I am relatively sure the question author wants to include that as well. And why do you use "\S"? It will match *anything but* whitespace, so it's wrong here.

Comment: I know . This will work in 2 ways : you test the /^\s+/ for matching , or you test the /^\S+/ for non-matching .

Comment: Hm, I did not think of the "non match" logic. Nice catch.

Comment: Nevertheless this is non-obvious, you should make the distinction clearer in your answer.

Comment: /^\S+$/ will give you a false positive on the input: "This is not empty". /^\s+$/ will give you a false negative on the input: "". If you find any ONE character which is not \s (ie: \S), then it's not empty. it's very simple!